# FB LOG IN RESTRICTIONS, allow only specific users to log in on your site using fb login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to make a website where only specific users can log in, and I was hoping to use FB LOG IN for this purpose,

is there a way to make only allowed users to log in using FB LOGIN SDK,

I already tried by using userID, but seems the userID I am getting is different from what I can get from their profile,
using their name isn't also reliable as anyone can create a dummy account with the same name, 
I cannot get their username showing on facebook.com/"username"

are there ways to get that or any other way to restrict the log in button

Answer (score 1):

You will only get an "App Scoped ID", and you will only get it after login. One way is to disallow access by default and activate access for specific users after they authorized your App.

You can also ask for the email, btw.

Comment: do you have links that I can follow to activate access to specific fb users only?

Comment: how to active access only to specific fb users, like anyone can visit the site with fb log in, then only specific users can log in to that fb login, 

here is what i got now.

I have the fb log in and when they log in I get their fb name,
and if the fb name is similar to specific users I would like to give access then they can see the restricted parts, tho this has a loop hole of making a dummy account with the same name will allow them to access. so are there any ways to only get a specific account to get to log in?

Comment: I have no way or I dont know how to get the App Scoped ID before they log in so I cannot restrict it before hand, if there is a way then this could work too.

Comment: i am not sure what else to tell you, there are 2 possible ways in my answer. (disallow by default and activate access AFTER login, or use the email to identify users)

Comment: disallow by default <-- this is something I don't know how to do

Comment: again, i am not sure what else to tell you...just don´t allow access by default, and if a user authorizes your app, activate his account so he can access your page. with an admin interface or whatever, there must be something where you can control access, right?